# Automating upload of artifacts in Nexus using Maven

Tags: maven-2, nexus

Am trying to automate the process of uploading an artifact generated by Maven into a Nexus hosted repository (like a maven goal, which will upload the generated jar into a specified repository in Nexus). Is this possible? In the Nexus docs they have talked only about manual uploading.

I also looked at the nexus maven plugins and nothing like this is specified.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240477/upload-download-entire-directory-to-nexus-through-maven

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `mvn deploy` to deploy your artifacts via WebDAV (declare the Nexus DAV URL in the `distributionManagement` section).

#### See also

- [Getting started with Nexus Maven Repo Manager](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-nexus-maven)
- [13.3. Configuring Maven for Site Deployment](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/ch13s03.html) (this link if for site deployment but it's similar)