# Upload/Download entire directory to Nexus through Maven

Tags: maven-2, upload, download, directory, nexus

Is it possible to upload/download an entire directory and all of the sub-directories within it to/from a Nexus repository server?

Comment: would that be an existing maven repo or some arbitrary files?

Comment: For uploading to the Nexus server, this is for arbitrary files.
For downloading from the server, I guess this would be from the Nexus repository.

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to actually deploy a hierarchy of files, I hacked together a solution using [GMaven](http://mostlymagic.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/deploy-a-folder-hierarchy-to-a-maven-repository/) (groovy embedded in maven).

Use the pom below, supply a few properties and hit `mvn install`.
The folder will be crawled and all files inside it will be deployed using an artifactId taken from the relative path. e.g.

Given the base folder

```
c:\a\b\c
```

the file

```
c:\a\b\c\def\ghi\jkl.mno
```

would have the artifactId `def-ghi-jkl` and the packaging `mno`, this can of course be changed to something else.

The repository info will be taken from the pom, so you need to supply a distributionManagement element in the pom.

Here it is (a lot of this code is taken from the [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) mojo):

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>folderdeployer</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- This is where your artifacts are -->
        <deploy.basefolder>c:\temp\stuff</deploy.basefolder>

        <!-- This will be used as groupId -->
        <deploy.groupId>my.groupid</deploy.groupId>

        <!-- this will be used as version -->
        <deploy.version>1.2.3</deploy.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-files</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>
                            <![CDATA[
// read components from plexus container             
def layout = session.lookup(
    'org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayout');
def repoFactory = session.lookup(
    'org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryFactory');
def repository = repoFactory.createDeploymentArtifactRepository(
    pom.distributionManagement.repository.id,
    pom.distributionManagement.repository.url,
    layout, true );
def localRepository = session.localRepository;
def helper =
    session.lookup("org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectHelper");
def afm = session.lookup(
    'org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.manager.ArtifactHandlerManager');
def factory = new org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory();
factory.class.getDeclaredField("artifactHandlerManager").accessible = true;
factory.artifactHandlerManager=afm;

def deployer = session.lookup(
    'org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeployer');

// initialize properties
def baseFolder = new File(pom.properties['deploy.basefolder']);
def groupId = pom.properties['deploy.groupId'];
def version = pom.properties['deploy.version'];

// iterate over all files recursively
baseFolder.eachFileRecurse{
    if(it.isDirectory())return;

    // packaging = file.extension
    def packaging = it.name.replaceAll( /.+\./ , '' );
    // artifactId = file.relativePath.replace '/' , '-'
    def artifactId = it.absolutePath
        .replace(baseFolder.absolutePath, '')
        .substring(1)
        .replaceFirst( /\..*?$/ , '')
        .replaceAll( /\W+/ , '-' );
    def artifact = 
        factory.createBuildArtifact( 
            groupId, artifactId, version, packaging );

    // create pom for artifact
    def model = new org.apache.maven.model.Model();
    model.setModelVersion( "4.0.0" );
    model.setGroupId( groupId );
    model.setArtifactId( artifactId );
    model.setVersion( version );
    model.setPackaging( packaging );
    File pomFile = File.createTempFile( "mvndeploy", ".pom" );
    pomFile.deleteOnExit();
    fw = org.codehaus.plexus.util.WriterFactory.newXmlWriter( pomFile );
    new org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Writer().write( fw, model );
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly( fw );

    def metadata = 
        new org.apache.maven.project.artifact.ProjectArtifactMetadata(
                    artifact, pomFile );
    artifact.addMetadata( metadata );

    // deploy file
    deployer.deploy(it, artifact, repository, localRepository );
}
                                    ]]>
                            </source>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>your repo id here</id>
            <url>scp://your.repo.url/here</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

---

EDIT:

I elaborated on this [on my blog](http://mostlymagic.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/deploy-a-folder-hierarchy-to-a-maven-repository/)

Comment: Interesting, I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Helpful! I modified it to fit local repository folder structure. https://gist.github.com/aleung/5194777

Comment: We've been using a modified version of @aleung script for almost a year now without problems
The modifications to handle 'maven-metadata.xml' and '.sha' and '.md5' files can be found in the forked gist: https://gist.github.com/jakub-bochenski/7802ee7f44b8e3b99bdd69b2ab150e6c

Answer (score 4):

You can always zip the directory and ship it as a zip file.
the users of this folder can download it from Nexus and unzip using dependency:unpack.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely one way to do it but does not completely satisfy the requirements. Thanks for the input though =)

Answer (score 0):

Not by default. But you can use the API of Nexus to upload by script. Here my script to upload the content of a local repository-folder. It uses the provided Information of the pom-files for upload of the artifacts.

Saves a lot of time and worked well for my usecase.

```
#!/bin/bash

# this script needs a "artifacts" file right next to it.  Create it by using following script in your .m2-folder
#       find -iname "*.pom" -printf "%h\n" > files; find -iname "*.jar" -printf "%h\n" >> files; cat files | sort | uniq -u > artifacts; rm files

NEXUS_USERNAME="admin"
NEXUS_PASSWORD="nexus"
NEXUS_URL="localhost:8081"

cat artifacts | while read i; do

    pompath=$(find $i -name *.pom)
    jarpath=$(find $i -name *.jar)
    
    # extracting metainformations from pom
    groupId=$(echo $pompath | xargs xpath -e 'project/groupId/text()')
    artifactId=$(echo $pompath | xargs xpath -e 'project/artifactId/text()')
    version=$(echo $pompath | xargs xpath -e 'project/version/text()')
    if test -z "$groupId"
    then 
        echo "project-groupId is empty - using parent/groupId"
        groupId=$(echo $pompath | xargs xpath -e 'project/parent/groupId/text()')
    fi
    
    if test -z "$version"
    then 
        echo "project-version of jar-pom is empty - using parent/version"
        version=$(echo $pompath | xargs xpath -e 'project/parent/version/text()')
    fi


    # choosing upload-strategy, preferring jar-upload
    if test -z "$jarpath"
    then
        echo "uploading $artifactId as pom"
        # a 400 error means that the artifactId already exists
        mvn deploy:deploy-file \
         -DgroupId=$groupId \
         -DartifactId=$artifactId \
         -Dversion=$version \
         -Dpackaging=pom \
         -Dfile=$pompath \
         -Durl="http://${NEXUS_USERNAME}:${NEXUS_PASSWORD}@${NEXUS_URL}/repository/maven-releases/"
        echo "uploading $pompath with groupId: $groupId; artifactId: $artifactId; version: $version"
    else 
        echo "uploading $artifactId as jar"
        # a 400 error means that the artifactId already exists
        mvn deploy:deploy-file \
         -DgroupId=$groupId \
         -DartifactId=$artifactId \
         -Dversion=$version \
         -Dpackaging=jar \
         -DgeneratePom=true \
         -Dfile=$jarpath \
         -Durl="http://${NEXUS_USERNAME}:${NEXUS_PASSWORD}@${NEXUS_URL}/repository/maven-releases"      
        echo "uploading $jarpath with groupId: $groupId; artifactId: $artifactId; version: $version"
    fi 
  
done 

echo 'done uploading artifacts'
```