# Is there a quick way to manually upload a bunch of artifacts jars with poms to archiva?

Tags: java, maven-2, archiva

The web UI is clunky, and since archiva is on the internal network, adding new updates and things to it is a painstaking process.

Does there exist a script or something that'll do the job of syncing up archiva to a local maven repo?

Comment: There was a similar question a few months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240477/upload-download-entire-directory-to-nexus-through-maven And I wrote about it in my blog: http://mostlymagic.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/deploy-a-folder-hierarchy-to-a-maven-repository/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a tool, your best bet is IMO to script something on top of `deploy:deploy-file`.

Comment: yea, I think that's what I'm going to do unless someone's already done this before.

Comment: so I recursed down a directory tree and found all the pom files, then I looked for accompanying jars and ran deploy:deploy-file.  This mostly worked.

Answer (score 1):

A few people have now requested this for Archiva - I'd encourage you to vote for the issue [MRM-875](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-875)

Comment: would it be possible to just copy over some directories from my repository to archiva's filesystem and run 'Scan repository Now'?